# What does Range_min Means

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

can i know what does param name="range_min" value="0.45" Means in the 3d sensor.launch

Thank in Advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174489/what-does-range_min-means/) by [vinod9910](https://answers.ros.org/users/18770/vinod9910/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means that the sensor readings that are less than the 'range_min' value will not be reported.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vinod9910](https://answers.ros.org/users/18770/vinod9910/) on 2014-06-23**:
Thank you.